# How to iterate over the list returned by a Java hibernate DAO that is accessed in UI as this.state.data using React JS?

Tags: javascript, html, hibernate, reactjs, react-native

This is the java code that returns a List

```
@Override
public List get_News(String lang) {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Query query =  session.createQuery("select n.text from tableName n where n.lang=:lang");
    query.setParameter("lang", lang);

    List result = query.list();

    if(result != null){
        if(result.iterator().hasNext()){
            return result;   //this is the result that is being returned
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Following is the React JS code

```
var Comment = React.createClass({
      displayName: "Comment",
      loadCommentsFromServer: function loadCommentsFromServer() {
            $.ajax({
              url: "/abc/ages",
              dataType: 'json',
              cache: true,
              success: function(data) {
                this.setState({data: data});
              }.bind(this),
              error: function(xhr, status, err) {
                }.bind(this)
            });
          },
      getInitialState: function(){
        return {data: []};
      },
      componentDidMount: function componentDidMount() {
          this.loadCommentsFromServer();

      },
      render: function render() {
        return React.createElement("div",{ className: "comment" },
          React.createElement("div", { },  this.state.data)   //I want to iterate over this data
        );
      }
    }); 

    function RenderComment(){
  ReactDOM.render(React.createElement("div", {}, React.createElement(Comment,{})),
                document.getElementById('content')
        );      
    }
```

As of now I am getting all text from database, but all rows get displayed as a single chunk of data. I want to iterate over the data and show as 
text1

text2

text3

rather than

text1
text2
text3

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

If the data is an array, you could do something like this (not sure if you're using react or react native):

**React**:

```
render() {

  var data = this.state.data.map((d) => {
    return <p>{d}</p>
  })

  return <div>
           {data}
         </div>

}
```

**React Native:**

```
render() {

  var data = this.state.data.map((d) => {
    return <Text>{d}</Text>
  })

  return <View>
           {data}
         </View>

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. data is a list.